# Run LightTPD as a Windows service for free

Tags: windows, services, windows-services, lighttpd

I'm looking for a good way to run LightTPD as a service on a Windows server, but all the solutions I can find are either general-purpose shareware or quite complicated to set up.

Is there any good and easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641658/running-lighttpd-as-a-windows-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know *why* [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415409/run-batch-file-as-a-windows-service) is on stack overflow, but to summarize:

There's a free tool called [RunAsService](http://runasservice.sourceforge.net/). With it, you should be able to configure a `.bat` or other executable to be launched as a service.

Comment: I actually ended up using [ServiceRunner](http://servicerunner.codeplex.com/) which basically does the same thing. [This is the batch file](http://pastebin.com/rW7dmVYU) that I had to use -- the /D parameter states the working directory for the command, which was apparently very important for it to work at all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [winsw](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw), a free (as in both freedom and beer) utility to run Lighttpd or any other program (Nginx, PHP-CGI, etc) as a service.

Download the winsw binary, rename it to `winsw` and put it in your Lighttpd root directory where your `lighttpd.exe` resides, and create a `winsw.xml` file in there with the following contents :

```
<service>
    <id>lighttpd</id>
    <name>LigHTTPd</name>
    <description>Lighttpd web server.</description>
    <executable>lighttpd</executable>
    <workingdirectory>C:\Lighttpd\</workingdirectory>
    <logmode>append</logmode>
</service>
```

Of course, adjust the paths as necessary if your Lighttpd lives somewhere else.

Finally, open an elevated (as an administrator) command prompt and issue the following commands : `winsw install` (that will register the service and set it to start automatically each boot) and `winsw start` to start the installed service right away.

Of course feel free to change the service's auto start settings in `services.msc`.